# obfusticating SQL credentials in a PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have a php script that accesses a local MySQL server, fetches some data, plays around with it and then outputs it to a webpage.

I want to eventually put this page up on github, publically, but for obvious reasons I do not want my SQL credentials in that file.

I created another file called code.php in the same directory and did a require_once to access the variables.

My problem is I would like to move that code.php out of the web server (/var/www/html) into some directory that cannot be accessed remotely. Or more to the point, so I don't accidentally add it to my git repository and post it.

I was also told that using environment variables would be an even better solution.

I don't know how to do either. I have run a shell_exec on a file that was outside of the web directory, but I think that's because I just needed to give the file execute access to apache's user account. The php file, on the other hand, is actually being served by the webserver so maybe that isn't possible in the same way? I'm quite confused.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can use gitignore to ignore the variable file

Comment: `echo 'config.php' >> .gitignore`

Comment: I know, but I'm still a novice and I've accidentally added the whole directory before.